# Change data element of html 5 object

Tags: html, object, jsf-2

Can someone please supply proven code for this.  I've looked throughout stackoverflow, several other forums and articles.  The questions is being asked often and the answers very similar, but the responses are invariable that the supplied solution does not work.  Here's one that I've tried.  We'll say I've entere http://www.amazon.com into the inputText and I'm trying to replace http://www.brisnet.com/cgi-bin/trk_report.cgi?drs#

xhtml

```
<h:inputText id="newUrlId" styleClass="bodyTextMediumIndent" size="100" value="#    {hhraDrf.newDrfUrl}" />
<h:commandButton id="goBtnId" onclick="refreshUrl()" value="Go" />

<divid="objectDivId">
<<object
    id='drfId'
    style='object-fit:contain;'
    data='http://www.brisnet.com/cgi-bin/trk_report.cgi?drs#'
    type='text/plain'
    width='1024px'
    height='768px'>
</object>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function refreshUrl() {
    myUrlValue = document.getElementById('hhraFormId:newUrlId').value;
    objectElement = document.getElementById('drfId');
    objectElement.style.display = "none";
    objectElement.data = myUrlValue;
    objectElement.style.display = "block"; 
}
```

I've put alerts in the javascript and myUrlValue is = http://www.amazon.com. alerts also indicate the correct current, original value of the object data as http://www.brisnet.com/cgi-bin/trk_report.cgi?drs#

In reality, it's simply redisplaying the original data element as http://www.brisnet.com/cgi-bin/trk_report.cgi?drs# and a check of the page source indicates it's still there.

I'm simply trying to change the URL and get it to redisplay that URL.

Comment: I've run into something similar in the past, and I don't remember finding a solution. When you change the data in js, it is indeed updated, but only accessible through js/css. Have you tried replacing the entire object element? I know that feels hacky, but at least see if you end up with the behavior you're looking for.